# Sum of Arrays In Given Range, Count of certain #'s in an Array etc

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am having trouble getting through my Java labs. I don't have the best instructor and they are due tomorrow. If someone could help me and give a brief summarization of the code, they would use. I have posted this lab description below and attached the code of the runner file in the comments.

Lab Description:   Write several array manipulation methods.  One method will sum up a section of a provided array, another method will count up how many of a certain number occur in the array, and the last method will remove all of a certain value from the array.

I have tried a forloop to iterate through the array and select the elements but I am stumped on how to select the range and add them.

Comment: import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayFunHouseRunner
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
  int[] one = {4,10,0,1,7,6,5,3,2,9};

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one));
  System.out.println("sum of spots 3-6  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getSum(one,3,6));
  System.out.println("sum of spots 2-9  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getSum(one,2,9));
  System.out.println("# of 4s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one,4));
  System.out.println("# of 9s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one,9));

  int[] two = {4,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,0,10,0,1,7,6,5,3,2,9,9,8,7};

  //add test cases


 }
}

Comment: Don't post code in the comments. [Edit] the post and add it with proper formatting.